# Disabling network discovery on Win10 via GPO?

Tags: networking, group-policy, discovery, controlpanel

I'm trying to disable network discovery on Win10 for Public and Private networks via GPO, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I've attempted the instructions here: https://alferkwok.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/disable-network-discovery-by-gpo-windows-vista-or-later/

```
- Enabled the following policies and checked the box "Allow operation while in domain":

   - Turn on Mapper I/O (LLTDIO) Driver

   - Turn on Responder (RSPNDR) Driver
```

Then, I checked the Control Panel (`Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`) and it looks like network discovery is still enabled across Public and Private networks. Any idea why this is? Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that if the Windows Defender firewall is off, then the GPO won't apply. Not sure why this is, though I theorize that, since the Defender firewall is responsible for creating rules about different network location types (domain, public, private), it doesn't accept any GPO because it's not in charge of making rules for those location types when it's off.